# How to position two boxes side by side using <div> tags?

Tags: css, html, alignment

im learning HTML and CSS right now. 
Now im trying to create a simple Layout, 
HEADER
below that a
A MENU BAR
and below that a
NAVIGATION BAR in the right and MAIN SECTION in the right
Im not able to place the navigation bar and the main section side by side.

THE main section goes below the navigation bar and not on its side

```
The code:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<center>
    <div style="height:70px; width:800px; background-color:red; color:white; font-size:30px" align="center">
    <strong>WELCOME</strong>
    </div>
    <div style="height:30px; width:800px; background-color:blue; color:white; font-size:15px; top:80px" align="center">
        <div style="width:200px; float:left">
            <a href="">HOME</a>
        </div>
        <div style="width:200px; float:left">
            <a href="C:\Users\Harish\Desktop\c prog.html">liwjoejlsn</a>
        </div>
        <div style="width:200px; float:left">
            <a href="">lskdjflsd</a>
        </div>
        <div style="width:200px; float:left">
            <a href="">ABOUT</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
<center>
    <div style="height:800px; width:800px; background-color:grey; color:white; font-size:10px; top:100px">
        <div style="height:800px; width:200px; float:left; border-style:solid; border-width:2px;">
            <ul>
                <li>Hello</li>
                <li>hey</li>
                <li>who is</li>
                <li>forgive</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="height:800px;width:600px; float:left; border-style:solid; border-width:2px; left:200px;">
            <p>
                lsjdgfio jsldfkslj;do fsmi;odfml dsijfo siuldhf iofj s dofus <br> klsjhdfioy oasdilufilh aoudsfk <br> ksajhkdfjhu aosls
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: first thing to look at is converting your inline styles to css classes and id selectors

Comment: well, yes. i know about that and tried it too, but the problem is, im not able to get the nav bar and main section side by side. How to do that ?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to have two `div` elements side by side you should use `float:left;`. As far as your code is concerned, you are using old code, such as `center` and you should really start naming your `div` elements. It would also be better if you placed your css code on a separate file and called it from your html.

There's too much to cover from just one post, but I did write up some small demos so you can see how `float:left;` works. I also fixed your code so now you have the divs side by side.

[FLOAT LEFT DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K8CQf/)

[YOUR CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6dcw/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much. 
What is the syntax of the margin in #nav ?

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` centers that particular `div`.

Comment: well, what is the 0 mean, and the auto mean?

Comment: the 0 means there is no margin and the auto means the browser will automatically set the margins at 0 so that left and right margins are equal.

Comment: You're welcome. If you found this answer useful, go ahead and accept this answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

in this example you can use

```
display: inline-block;
```